# How do I loop through the json object returned from the controller?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am returning JSON result to the view from controller. I want to loop through it in RAZOR

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    return Json(GalleryRepository.getImages(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

in view:

```
@model ZahidCarWash.ViewModels.GetImagesViewModel
    @{
        foreach(var i in )
     }
```

getimages function:

```
public static List<GetImagesViewModel> getImages()
    {

        List<GetImagesViewModel> lstImages = new List<GetImagesViewModel>();

        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        try
        {
            string ConnectionString = Utility.getConnectionString();

            conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("getImages", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Adapter.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();


            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                GetImagesViewModel getImagesVM = new GetImagesViewModel();

                getImagesVM.ID = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ID"]);
                getImagesVM.Image = Convert.ToString(dr["Image"]);

                lstImages.Add(getImagesVM);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        return lstImages;
    }
```

I want to loop through the values that are being returned.

Comment: is there a special reason why you are returning a json string instead of just a view with your viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller Action to this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(GalleryRepository.getImages());
}
```

and change your view to something like this:

```
@model List<ZahidCarWash.ViewModels.GetImagesViewModel>
@{
    foreach(var i in Model)
    {
       //do something with the image  
    }
 }
```